# Flash Flex locally storing XML returned from RESTful api in mobile app

Tags: iphone, xml, apache-flex, flash-builder, dreamfactory

I have created a basic mobile login form in Flex Builder 4.6 that retrieves an XML file from a RESTful api which includes a session_token which then must be used in all subsequent calls to that API.  It also returns some other useful information such as full name of user.

I want to store this XML locally and then retrieve the session_token at will from any tab within the app.

Here is the form

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:session="services.session.*"
    title="HomeView">
<fx:Script>

    <![CDATA[

            protected function LoginButton_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var strXmlTextInput2:String = "<dfapi><email>" + emailInput.text + "</email><password>" + passwordInput.text + "</password><duration>7200</duration></dfapi>";
            GetSessionResult.token = session.GetSession(strXmlTextInput2);
             // unhide below to go to next view
            // navigator.pushView(views.detailView);
        }
    ]]>


</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <s:CallResponder id="GetSessionResult"/>
    <session:Session id="session"/>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:VGroup x="60" y="35" width="200" height="218" horizontalAlign="left" verticalAlign="middle">
    <s:Label text="Email"/>
    <s:TextInput id="emailInput" width="199" text="tom@when23.com"/>
    <s:Label text="Password"/>
    <s:TextInput id="passwordInput" width="201" text="123456"/>
    <s:Label text="Session Token"/>
    <s:TextInput id="textInput" width="200" text="{GetSessionResult.lastResult.session_token}"/>
</s:VGroup>
<s:Button id="LoginButton" x="126" y="261" label="Login" click="LoginButton_clickHandler(event)"/>
```

When I click the button the session token appears in the Session Token field on the same View returned from

```
    text="{GetSessionResult.lastResult.session_token}
```

...so that works but how do I save the XML so it is available to all tabs, views etc and also on app startup? How do I use the variable session_token in subsequent calls to the API (it needs to be added as a parameter ....?session_token=xxxxx, and I know how to do that).

I have tried setting and getting but I am afraid I am too much of a beginner to get any of the examples I have googled to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedObjects to do it. I use in my mobile app to stores some data because my app needs works off-line. I have list of 5k + itens, all stored in local device provide  by SharedObjects. Works really fine.